# Meteor accounts - Custom login page

Tags: html, meteor, authentication, meteor-accounts

In Meteor, I am using accounts-base plugin for authentication system. Now, I need to create custom login page, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 6):

Here's the most basic html and js that will let you start your work. Put both files into client folder of your app.

client/login.html

```
<template name="login">
 <h1>Custom login page for Aparna</h1>
 <form>
  <p>Email:</p>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" /><br />
  <p>Password:</p>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
</template>
```

You'll need to include the login template into your main template, depending on where and how you want your login form implemented and which router you use.

client/login.js

```
Template.login.events({
 'submit form': function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var email = event.target.email.value;
  var password = event.target.password.value;
  Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password);
 }
});
```

You can see here that we use the function `LoginWithPassword` which is provided by `accounts-password` package.

I'll recommend you few good tutorials to extend this functionality:

[Meteor custom login and signup form](http://www.wsvincent.com/meteor-custom-login-and-signup-form/)

[Extending meteor users](https://medium.com/all-about-meteorjs/extending-meteor-users-300a6cb8e17f)

[Adding attributes to the user object when creating a new user](http://justmeteor.com/blog/adding-attributes-to-the-user-object-when-creating-a-new-user/)

There's also an additional suite of Meteor packages called [User Accounts](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/core) that will do all that (and more) for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Can you please help me with the reset password and forgot password tooo...

Comment: Thai is; i want to actually know how to use Accounts.changePassword(oldPassword, newPassword, [callback]) and Accounts.forgotPassword(options, [callback]) ? Can anyone show me the answer with an example

Comment: When you accept this answer as valid one and form another Stack Overflow question regarding password change, I'll be happy to answer it.

Comment: Since i did not earn 15 rep till now, my vote isnt considered as public now. Anyway thankyou for your response